# How does 'std::string::c_str()' return a C string that does not cause a memory leak or undefined C string contents?

Tags: c++, string, memory, c-strings

I'm writing a string class that is similar to *std::string* for a homework assignment, but I cannot figure out how to return a C string that does not cause a memory leak and is guaranteed to stay the same until it is no longer in use. I currently have:

```
const char* string::c_str()
{
    char c[_size + 1];
    strncpy(c, _data, _size);
    c[_size] = '\0';
    return c;
}
```

but the contents are overridden shortly after it is called. If I do dynamic allocation, I'll have either a memory leak or only one C string can exist from a given string at any time. How can I avoid this?

Comment: "*or only one c-string can exist from a given string at any time*" This is how `std::string` works -- what's the problem?

Comment: If `strncpy()` is the answer, you're probably [asking the wrong question](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html).

Comment: I didn't realize it had to only exist until changed. It now works in O(1) time.

Comment: I did see a horrible hack once, in code that had huge piles of temporary strings that kept getting use-after-free bugs. It kept a global std::deque of c_str allocations and freed one off the front when making a new one. Considering all the locking overhead involved that may not have been a good idea but it was a quick fix. Also horrible because it redefined std::string in a local header file, which is supposed to not be a good idea.

Comment: @ZanLynx also horrible because AFAICT it had no way of knowing for sure that the string it freed was actually no longer in use... I suspect it was just hoping that the dequeue was big enough, that it wouldn't be.

Comment: Just return `_data`? That's all `std::string` does

Answer (score 7, accepted):

But the string pointed to by `c_str` is only well-defined until the `std::string` is next modified (or destroyed).

One way to achieve this might be simply to return a pointer to your internal buffer (assuming it's null-terminated).  Bear in mind that a standards-compliant `c_str` has to operate in O(1) time; so copying is not permitted.

Comment: Good to know. That is almost like forcing a certain implementation of the `std::string` class, namely as an array of characters.

Answer (score 4):

From *[std::string::c_str](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/)*:

> The returned array points to an internal location with the required
> storage space for this sequence of characters plus its terminating
> null-character, but the values in this array should not be modified in
> the program and are only guaranteed to remain unchanged until the next
> call to a non-constant member function of the string object.

Comment: Related: *[When should answers consisting entirely of cited, copied content be flagged?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404102)*

Answer (score 1):

The buffer returned by *c_str()* isn't guaranteed to stay the same or even valid until it's no longer used.

It's only guaranteed to stay valid until the *std::string* is changed in any way.

The implementation is straightforward: just keep the internal representation of the string null-terminated at all times, and return a pointer to the internal representation from *c_str()*.